# Why Active Record relation is not returned in console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, irb

I have finally started upgrading my Rails apps from 2.3.8 to 3.1.0. I was watching RailsCasts (http://railscasts.com/episodes/202-active-record-queries-in-rails-3) about Active Record queries.

When I open up the console (rails c) and do query similar to this:

```
articles = Article.order("name")
```

Instead of returning Active Record relations, I see the query executed. What am I doing wrong here?

Rails version: 3.1.0

RVM on 1.9.2

Thank you for your help!

---

EDIT: I have added a screenshot from the example. 
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're doing everything right. You see query executed because console invokes `inspect` method on output. Try `articles = Article.order("name").class`

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the issue. I have added a screenshot from the example. Do you have any idea why the inspect method is not invoked in the example video?

Comment: Man, did I struggle with this the first time I tried playing with Arel.

Answer (score 9):

The ActiveRecord Relation class is configured to perform the query when a query method like `.all`, `.last`, `.first`, ... is invoked. The list of method also includes `.inspect`, the same method called by the console to display the representation of the return value.

For this reason it seems to you that the object is never a relation, because you always see the result of the query.

But if you inspect the object class, you'll notice it's a relation

```
Article.order("name").class
# => ActiveRecord::Relation
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I chose Bohdan's answer because he posted it a bit earlier. +