# Lazy loading in Rails 3.2.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have found in several resources online than when doing stuff like:

```
cars = Car.where(:colour => 'black')
```

The query is not executed, until you do something like:

```
cars.each {|c| puts c.name }
```

However, in my Rails 3.2.6 project, when I do the following in the console:

```
User.where(:first_name => "John")
```

I get the following:

```
 User Load (1.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`first_name` = 'John'
```

So, the query is being executed right?

Where did the lazy loading go? Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The console calls `inspect` on the result of any expression you type so that it can display it to you. `inspect` is one of the things that will trigger the load of the query. If you instead do

```
x = User.where(:first_name => 'John'); false
```

then you should see no query because this time the console is calling inspect on `false` instead of on the Active Record relation object.

Comment: This is one of those situations where exploring in the dynamic environment of the console (usually a fruitful endeavor) can actually lead to confusion about how ActiveRecord works. I've known about this lazy-loading behavior, yet I still get tripped up by this occasionally. I really like your "; false" idea. Will try to make that part of my muscle memory when tooling around in the console.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! Exactly what things would trigger a query load on an ActiveRecord::Relation object? `pluck`, say?

Comment: @kitkat pluck runs a query that just returns the column values rather than AR objects. Anything like each, map, reject, to_a etc. will cause the relation to be loaded. There's basically a method missing on Relation that will load the target and forward the method call to it.

Answer (score 3):

This is an interesting question....The answer is that when executing something in IRB/console, it calls inspect on the resulting object and then prints it out.  If you did something like:

```
User.where(:first_name => "John").class
```

you should get back an ActiveRecord::Relation object.

So the lazy loading for Rails still holds, it's just the way the console works.

Hope this helps.

Source(s): 
1) https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4951-rails-console-executes-where-queries-without-lazy-loading
2) [Why Active Record relation is not returned in console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646199/why-active-record-relation-is-not-returned-in-console)

Answer (score -1):

I ran a test using sqllite3 to attempt to find out if the AR Base find actually did a query immediately. Here is what I did:

```
rows=Customer.orders.find(1,2)
```

Then I did:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.remove_connection;
p rows
```

I got a connection not established error.

I also tried "p rows" immediately after the query w/o removing the connection and got the 2 rows I expected.

This was done with activerecord-3.1.3. My conclusion is that in 3.1.3 base find waits to do the query until the array (Relation?) is accessed.

I'm new at Ruby so my test might not be designed correctly.

Comment: Might want to move the conclusion to the top so people don't mistake this for a "I'm having this problem too" post.