# Active record create query in multiple steps

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a bit confused by active record, it just seems to fire the query at any time you stop, ie.

```
@model.where( :store_id => @sid )
```

Which is fine, but what if I want to build a query like this:

```
query = @model.where( :store_id => @sid )

if(some_condition)
  query.offset(50)
```

and then execute the query (not actually what I'm doing but a very simple example). Is there a way to put together the query in steps and then tell it to execute?

Comment: I think what you mean is not ActiveRecord issue, it's just Ruby returning last evaluated expression. So if you have conditionals like you wrote it will execute only the last compound query

Comment: @Fenec I'm not sure that makes much sense to me but it seems to be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This already works like you want it too.

`where()` returns an instance of `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

The relation won't execute it's database call until it needs to. The reason you might be experiencing otherwise is that you're testing it in the console, which  prints the output of each statement (thus loading the relation). You can test whether a relation has been loaded via the `loaded()` method.

Try this on the console:

```
m = @model.where(:store_id => @sid); # the semicolon will silence the output

m.loaded?  # nil
m          # executes db call, will print out the contents of the relation
m.loaded?  # true
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, ActiveRecord will do exactly what you want. It's called lazy loading. You might be getting confused by the rails console, which calls `.inspect` behinds the scenes on the result of the line.

Check out this question: [Lazy loading in Rails 3.2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11702341/lazy-loading-in-rails-3-2-6)